# Make dynamically generated select box value available in form params

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I feel like there should be a really simple solution to this... but i can't find it.

I am using jquery to dynamically generate a select box within a form that is dependent on another select box.

Extract of the form code in my view:

```
form_for @unit do |f|

    <td> f.collection_select :shop_id, @shops, :id, :name </td>     # this is the first select box

    <td id="options"></td>     # this is the id tag that jquery finds and replaces with the second select box, depending on the value of the first select box
```

In my **application.js** I have the function that grabs the value of the first select box and sends it to my controller:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // when the #shop field changes
    $("#unit_shop_id").change(function() {

    var shop_id
    shop_id = $('select#unit_shop_id :selected').val();

    // make a GET call and replace the content
    jQuery.get('/units/options/' + shop_id )
    return false;
    });
});
```

and in my **units_controller** I set the options for the second select box based on the shop_id and call the js.erb file:

```
def options     # note params[:id] is the shop_id specified by the first select box

    if params[:id] == 0 
        @options = ["Yes", No", "Maybe"]
            elsif params[:id] == 1
                @options = ["Yes", Maybe"]
            else
                @options = ["Yes"]
            end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
    end
end
```

My **options.js.erb** file dynamiclaly displays my second select box:

```
$("#options").html( "<%= escape_javascript(select("product_id", @options)) %>" );
```

This all works perfectly. My form displays, and when I choose a value in my first select box it determines the options available in my second select box.

What I'm struggling with is how to add the value choosen in my second select box to the form params.

The form params generated are:

```
    "unit"=>{"shop_id"=>"x"}    (i.e. only the first select box)
```

I want to generate form params that include the second select box dynamically generated by jquery, i.e:

```
    "unit"=>{"shop_id"=>"x", "product_id=>"y"}
```

Any idea how this can be done? I've tried using a hidden_field in the form for product_id, but I can't seem to reference the product_id successfully.

Comment: Any luck with this one? Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select), it looks like `select` is defined as follows:

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

I believe that using both the **object** (`unit`) and the **method** (`product_id`) should give you the desired behavior.

```
$("#options").html( "<%= escape_javascript(select("unit", "product_id", @options)) %>" );
```